# UWP RequestedTheme in resource dictionary

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10

So I am designing an app that dynamically themes itself based upon an API response. I have been able to programmatically set the colors in the resource dictionary for the rest of my app but I am trying to find out how to set get the button and AppBarButton hover and click colors to fit in my color scheme. I have previously changed this by hardcoding the RequestedTheme property in the required elements.

Is there a way to bind the RequestedTheme property to a static resource set in a resource dictionary that I am able to set programmatically? I am open to accomplishing the theming of the buttons differently if need be but would like to avoid having to bind to a local variable on each page if possible.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a custom theme resource class like the following:

```cs
public enum MyTheme
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Use the Application.RequestedTheme value for the element. This is the default.
    Default = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Use the **Light** default theme.
    Light = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Use the **Dark** default theme.
    Dark = 2
}
```

Then, in resource dictionary, you could define your different theme resource:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:MyTheme x:Key="MyTheme">Light</local:MyTheme>
</Application.Resources>
```

In XAML page, you could reference to it:

```
<Button Content="test" RequestedTheme="{StaticResource MyTheme}"></Button>
```

You can then change the value in code with:

```
App.Current.Resources["MyTheme"] = isThemeDark ? "Dark" : "Light";
```

Comment: But if I am just binding to the light resource, if I wanted to change that while running the program wouldn't I have to go and change the XAML programmatically on every page?

Comment: Yeah. You would need to change it by programming.